# windows server 2008: Cant see static data in the intranet of my network, but from the outside can

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, website

we have a windows server 2008, we installed some websites in PHP, and we cannot see them if we are in the network, or placing the IP/website (actually the static data e.g images, css won't appear..), but if we put the name of the server in the explorer it works..., displays the static data without a problem and if we are outside the network, and we use the ip of the server we can see the websites without a problem, how can we fix it?? where can i start?

Technicall information:

```
* If: in a computer of the network we type IP/website or DynDns domain >> Fails to display static data
* If: in a computer of the network we type SERVERNAME/website or DynDns domain >> SUCCESS to display static data
* If: we are in the server, or outside the Network e.g in my house >> SUCCESS All methods (IP, DynDNS, SERVERNAME) works!!
```

We have dinamics IPs, and we have a DHCP using ipV4 and ipV6, and the switch is a netgear that does not need configuration.

Thanks for the help...

Comment: You say it is failing, how is it failing. Do yo get a page not found error, blank page?

Comment: which webserver you are using ? IIS or Apache ? anyway, you must paste some server error logs here. matching with requests when it's not sending the static files.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable 'Static Content'.

Please see these links:

[Link 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx)

[Link 2](http://msdn.itags.org/iis/13706/)

[Link 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/53314/iis7-returns-blank-when-static-content-requested)